# How can I do fragment injection on ToggleAccessibilityServicePreferenceFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, settings, accessibility

I am trying to use fragment injection on android to invoke *com.android.settings.accessibility.ToggleAccessibilityServicePreferenceFragment* of my app's Accessibility Service.

Here is the code:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
i.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings");
ComponentName name = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), "MyAccessibilityService");
i.putExtra(PreferenceActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT, "com.android.settings.accessibility.ToggleAccessibilityServicePreferenceFragment");
i.putExtra("mComponentName", name);
startActivity(intentTT);
```

But after executing those code, the LogCat showed this :

```
E/Settings:###(9542): onApplyThemeResource...
E/HtcPreferenceActivity(9542): context.getClassLoader(): dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/app/Settings.apk]
E/HtcPreferenceActivity(9542): context.getPackageName(): com.android.settings
E/HtcPreferenceActivity(9542): context.getPackageCodePath(): /system/app/Settings.apk
E/HtcPreferenceActivity(9542): context.getPackageResourcePath(): /system/app/Settings.apk
E/HtcPreferenceActivity(9542): fragmentName: com.android.settings.accessibility.ToggleAccessibilityServicePreferenceFragment
E/AndroidRuntime(9542): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(9542): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.settings/com.android.settings.Settings}: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.android.settings.accessibility.ToggleAccessibilityServicePreferenceFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
```

I tried to invoke this fragment with "nComponentName" extra set to my app and then go to the accessibility service page of my app.

Here is the part of android source code :

```
public class ToggleAccessibilityServicePreferenceFragment
            extends ToggleFeaturePreferenceFragment implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
        private static final int DIALOG_ID_ENABLE_WARNING = 1;
        private static final int DIALOG_ID_DISABLE_WARNING = 2;
        private final SettingsContentObserver mSettingsContentObserver =
            new SettingsContentObserver(new Handler()) {
                @Override
                    public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
                        String settingValue = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                                Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES);
                        final boolean enabled = settingValue.contains(mComponentName.flattenToString());
                        mToggleSwitch.setCheckedInternal(enabled);
                    }
                };
        private ComponentName mComponentName;
        private int mShownDialogId;
```

or you can go to this page of source code to see : https://goo.gl/c4UGw9

Is there any `other extras` that I need to set/put ? I am trying to fix the problem for over one month. But still can't solve it. Is there anything I missed ?